# Using TortoisePLink in GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "-batch" switch not respected

Tags: windows, git, powershell, ssh-keys, plink

(OS: Windows; using PowerShell)

#### Background

I intend to have "git pull" run from time to time by my service (i.e. Windows Service). In order to achieve it I use TortoiseGitPLink to provide git with my SSH key every time it's needed. This is done by setting the env var:

```
$env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND="'C:/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoisePlink.exe' -i c:/path/to/my/key/id_rsa.ppk -pw myKeyPassword"
```

This works fine in general, but if I make a mistake and specify wrong path to my SSH key or wrong password, then TortoisePLink hangs indefinitely, freezing therefore my service. Also, If I stop the service, there's still TortoisePLink process hanging around.

Reading Plink's doc I found a "-batch" switch:

```
-batch: disable all interactive prompts
```

but for some reason either it is not respected or I use it in a wrong way.

#### Question

Is there a way to use TortoiseGitPLink to reliably provide an SSH key? By "reliably" I mean: it should fail if any pop-up appears or the key file is missing.